# JList like component in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to have List Component which is basicaly list of Labels(String) and I can select element by touching then get selelection position number. Which Component is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ListBox? It has properties like SelectedIndex, SelectedItem & SelectedValue and can use simple Strings as items.